# What are ball bearings for in coaster brakes?

Tags: road-bike, single-speed, coaster

[image: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Edwin-Odom/publication/2528341/figure/fig4/AS:652224900366344@1532513942192/Hand-drawn-sketch-of-the-coaster-brake-bicycle-hub-dissected-by-students.png]

I tried to fix my coaster brake with no understanding of what I was doing. Suffice to say it's a long process.

I broke one of the ball bearing cages in disassembly, so I thought they were pointless fragile things and I threw them out. A bike can work on plain bearings, right?

From what I can tell, they were there to keep the hub from bouncing around on the axle. Now the chain won't stay on anymore. But I want a second or fifth opinion.

Comment: Can you post pictures?  It's a bit hard to imagine what you mean by "I broke one of the ball bearings in disassembly".  FWIW, coaster brakes are integrated into the rear hub.  You likely reassembled the hub without parts of the bearings that support the entire wheel on the axle and allow it to spin properly around that axle.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Right. I've added a link.

Comment: "I thought they were pointless fragile things and I threw them out. " - in the future, save decisions like that for things you are an expert in, rather than subjects you have "no understanding" of.

Comment: @whatsisname You're right, but in hindsight I like the idea of loose bearings and tacky grease. From what I can tell you can't buy caged bearings separately. It's really just as well.

Answer (score 2):

> What are ball bearings for in a coaster brake?

The bearings allow the hub to spin freely around the axle.
Cadged bearings decrease friction and make repair much easier than loose balls.

Your sketch looks something like this diagram
[image]

> I broke one of the ball bearings in disassembly, so I thought they were pointless fragile things and I threw them out. A bike can work on plain bearings, right?

You broke one of the ball bearings during disassembly. This could mean that one of the individual balls was broken or that the retaining ring holding the ball bearings broke.

You threw out the broken bearings and then you say "A bike can work on plain bearings, right?"
This may mean that you put bearings in without the metal cage.
This is theoretically possible using loose bearings of the same size.

- Coat the bearing surface you want to load bearings on with a tacky grease so the bearings will stick.
- Fill the space where the cage lived with loose balls and then remove one so there is room for them to move.

Use the same size bearings as the ones that came out of the hub.

It might take some experimentation to get right.

Comment: Seems easy. Where's a good place to buy these things?

Comment: Plain bearing a type of bearing that has simply two smooth lubricated surfaces sliding against each other. Typically one of them is soft porous metal so that it can bed in and retain lubricant. And no, ball bearing races without bearings don't work that way.

Comment: My interpretation was that Ethan just reassembled the wheel without any bearings, not realising that the entire weight of the bike and rider are supported by the little spherical jobbies. hence the wobbling around and needing to buy some new ones. Worrying!

Comment: @EthanMiller bike spares are traditionally available from bike shops, though you will need some idea of the size you need, have you got any of the old ones remaining? Rear wheels I've seen have typically been 1/4 inch

Comment: @Swifty Is that 1/4 inch outside or inside diameter?

Comment: @EthanMiller yes

Comment: @Swifty Yes what? And what about thickness?

Comment: @EthanMiller It would be best to measure the ball bearings you took out of the hub. They need to be the same size as what came out of the hub. Knowing the hub make and model might help locate documentation if you don't have the bearings to measure.

Comment: @EthanMiller individual bearing balls have a diameter, and that's it.  They're solid through.   If you're looking at a caged bearing then that will have a separate diameter, but the thickness is related to the bearing balls inside.   You can't fit a cartridge bearing unit where loose balls were intended to go.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not stupid. I clearly meant to ask what the inside and outside diameter of the caged bearings are.

Comment: @DavidD I see. So they're not really standardized across manufacturers.

Comment: @EthanMiller -grin- I never meant to imply anything like that.  Apologies if it came across offensively.  The best solution would be to measure the previous cage, but you can try measuring the ID or OD approximately across the bearing races.  It won't be accurate but will get you in the ballpark.  You'll need some calipers.